# Cordova and Windows Phone, calling cordova.exec

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8

I need some help trying to execute a plugin using the cordova.exec using Phonegap.

I followed the tutorial here: [WP plugin tutorial](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_windows-phone_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Windows%20Phone)

However When I try to run this I get the following error:

```
Error::Plugin not allowed in config.xml. Echo
```

Here is how I am calling it from javascript:

```
cordova.exec(function(){ console.log("success");}, function(){console.log("fail");}, "Echo", "echo", ["input string"]);
```

here is my Echo.cs

```
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.JSON;

namespace Cordova.Extension.Commands
{
    public class Echo : BaseCommand
    {
        public void echo(string options)
        {
          string optVal = JsonHelper.Deserialize<string[]>(options)[0];

          DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "Everything went as planned, this is a result that is passed to the success handler."));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just add to config.xml

```
<feature name="Echo">
    <param name="wp-package" value="Echo" />
</feature>
```

the plugin name="Echo" is deprecated and doesn't work anymore